# svnadmin dump stopped due to an error within one of the revisions

Tags: svn

i get an error while performing an svnadmin dump on my current svn repository. the dump errorred out on a specific revision because that revision contains an error with no date and user information. however, the user information and date is displayed using Trac but TortoiseSVN shows ###error### on the specific revision. one of my associates was able to perform the dump a while back but he is no longer with the company and i need to transfer the old repository currently at version 1.4 to a new svn server with version 1.6.11. i am not sure how he did it. can anyone help? 
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the total number of revisions in the repository is 1500 and the missing revision is 750.

1. Take a repository dump from revision 1 to revision 749.

`svnadmin dump /path/to/current/repo -r1:749 --incremental > first.dump`

1. Create the new repository and import the dump `first.dump`

`svnadmin create newsvn_repo`

`svnadmin load newsvn_repo < first.dump`

1. After import you can checkout from newsvn_repo and add/update the files as per revision 750 in your old repo.(provided you need this revision in the new repo)
2. Take another repository dump from revision 751 to revision 1500 and load the same to new repository

`svnadmin dump /path/to/current/repo -r751:1500 --incremental > second.dump`

`svnadmin load newsvn_repo < second.dump`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer Dipu! I'll keep your method in mind as well. 
I found out that one of the revision was manually modified by someone and had the incorrect timestamp and character count within the revision file. I had to correct the timestamp and the comment count on the file with the revision number under the actual repository's db/revprops folder to match what was showing on my Trac page. The dump works now.